# Disable the custom functionality of Enable Property of custom Control Win Form

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I have a custom control. 
I want to override the default functionality of Enable property.
 By default when a customer Enable property is set to "False" it gray out the control.
but i do not want the control to do so.

what i can do to stop the default behavior.

As that is a custom control i want to style it in my own way when its Enable Property set to "False"

Thanks

Comment: I *think* that you would customize the OnPaint behavior based on whether the property Enabled is false and you are currently In DesignMode / Design Time. Or you have to use a custom Designer or get an IDesignerHost  I'm just spit balling here. Hopefully some of those terms can aid you in a Google search

Answer (score 0):

You can try overload OnPaint method like [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.onpaint?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Forms_ToolStripItem_OnPaint_System_Windows_Forms_PaintEventArgs_)